# tkinter Frame does not detect <Motion> event

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, frame, motion

Why `tkinter.Frame` in python does not work with `someframe.bind("<Motion>", somefunc)`? In this case `somefunc` does not get executed. Can someone please explain this to me?

code:
`self.frame.bind("<Motion>", tippy.update)`

If I bind this to for example `tkinter.Label`, everything works as expected. Code is executed.

EDIT: I thought that if I have `tkinter.Label` in `tkinter.Frame` and if I hover the mouse over the `tkinter.Label`, it will get executed because its in the `tkinter.Frame`. However `tkinter.Frame` detects movement only if there is no other widget in the place. Basically i thought that `tkinter.Frame` space is not overwrited with `tkinter.Label`.

Comment: We'll need more information to be able to answer the question. Please edit your post to include the piece of code that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Have you ensured that your frame has focus.

Comment: That should not affect that.

Comment: The frame _does_ work with the `<Motion>` event. Please show an [mcve] that illustrates why you think it doesn't.

Comment: @SolarFactories: focus only related to keyboard events, not mouse events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code demonstrates that the `<Motion>` event does work with a `Frame` widget in tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(*args):
    print("Motion detected")

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)

frame.bind("<Motion>", callback)

frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you can provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can try and help you through whatever problem you're having.